# check constraint violated sql error occur

Tags: sql

```
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_SPLFEATURES CHECK ((special_features ='Trailers') OR(special_features ='Commentaries') OR(special_features ='Deleted Scenes') OR(special_features ='Behind the Scenes'));
```

check constraint violated

I get this error, it worked for other thing but not this one

Comment: so what's the error ?

Comment: Please add information about your table.
To verify the answer from Lennart you could do a `Select special_feature from YOUR_TABLE group by special_feature`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have some data that violates the constraint. You can find out by negating the expression:

```
select ... from T 
where not (
   (special_features ='Trailers') OR(special_features ='Commentaries')
 OR(special_features ='Deleted Scenes') OR(special_features ='Behind the Scenes')
);
```